# Tag wiki editing policy inconsistencies

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagwiki, privileges

On an empty tag wiki page ([e.g. here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/latex-general/info)) it says that

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with
>   more than 1500 reputation, provided: They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or they hold the bronze tag badge for this tag.

On a tag wiki page with content ([e.g. here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/pdftex/info), provided that you don't have enough rep to edit [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex)), it says

> To edit this wiki, you must have at
>   least 2000 reputation and hold the
>   bronze tag badge for this tag.

Further, the [privileges page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki) says that one needs 1500 rep and

> either be in the top 20 answerers for the tag, or have a total score of 100 or more for the tag in question.

The last clause is not quite equivalent to a bronze tag badge (which also says 'in at least 20 non-CW questions').

This is clearly inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just updated all these spots, thanks for bringing them up.

With regards to the req, we require the bronze badge for tag wiki editing (if you are not in the top 20), the missing req is now documented

Comment: This will be deployed later today

Comment: Currently, I have the third highest rep on the site and I'm not quite eligible to edit any tag wikis (at least no bronze badges for the tags, I don't know how to check if I'm in the top 20 or not). I suspect others are in similar positions. Something seems off about these requirements.

Comment: I take that back, you can see who the top users for a particular tag are, although I don't know how to interpret the two columns of numbers. I do seem to be able to edit some of the tag wikis, although I don't know how to tell if I can ex ante.

Comment: @TH: the first column is the number of upvotes for answers in this tag, the second column the number of answers posted in this tag.

Comment: @waffles. Thank you. The privileges page still misses the second bronze tag requirement though.

Comment: @Caramdir: Ah, thanks.